# Javascript code to click a button once and if the code runs again not to click it

Tags: javascript

I got this code over here

```
 var el = document.getElementsByClassName('ef_button'); 

for (var i=0;i<el.length; i++) 
{
    if ( el[i].innerHTML.indexOf('EF') != -1 ) 
    {
         el[i].click();
    }

}
```

With this code the button EF is clicked all good.
But when i run it again i want it not to be clicked
Anyone has any idea about what to write in the 
"else" section after the code??

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('ef_button'); 

    for (var i=0;i<el.length; i++) 
    {
        if ( el[i].innerHTML.indexOf('EF') != -1 ) 
        {
             el[i].click();
        }
        else
       {
                     *something*
       }
```

}

Comment: use `<obj>.disabled=true;`

Comment: @Prashant  after else???

Comment: toggle(); <- look it up :)

Comment: @Prashant i tried    button.disabled=true;    after else but it didnt work

Comment: @AJ_91 this is for JQuery right? i only want javascript solution for not pushing again the same button if it is pushed !

Comment: try adding obj.disabled = true ,  after obj.click();

Comment: @gopinathshiva i added el[i].disabled=true;  but it didnt work either, its still pushing all the buttons

Comment: add a condition that if the button is enabled only, then push the click events

Comment: check my updated answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var el = document.getElementsByClassName('ef_button'); 

for (var i=0;i<el.length; i++) 
{
    if ( el[i].innerHTML.indexOf('EF') != -1 ) 
    {
         if(!el[i].disabled){
             el[i].click();
             el[i].disabled = true;
         }             
    }    
}
```

Comment: Lets say that you have 2 buttons. And you use my code to click them. The buttons are clicked all good. After 1 hour they appear other 3 buttons and when you run my code, the first 2 button are unclicked and the new 3 buttons are clicked. I want the code to clicke the new 3 buttons but not to unclick the first 2. But only with javascript code like the one that i posted

Comment: 'But not to unclick the first 2' -> cant get that

Comment: The buttons when you click them, from "EF" they change to "UF" button so i want any UF button NOT to be clicked, only the EF buttons should be clicked... OR to check if "EF button" is clicked not to click it.

Comment: Use an array of booleans stating whether the buttons are clicked and when one of them is clicked run the code and change the value at the correct index as true.

Comment: @gopinathshiva its doing the same work as my code above... still clicks all the buttons, even if they are clicked before